# Entanglement purification implementation with Qiskit

Tags: qiskit, entanglement

I'm quite new to qiskit, does anyone have any idea how to use the reset mechanism in qiskit to perform EPP? As in the protocol one EPR pair needs to be measured and the results are checked to accept/reject the other pair.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.